# R - How to add a logical column in a dataframe checking if a record exists in the whole dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe like this:

```
|Type  |Date      |Material|Customer|
|Quote |01-01-2020|A       |Cust1   |
|Quote |01-02-2020|B       |Cust2   |
|Quote |05-03-2020|C       |Cust3   |
|Order |03-01-2020|A       |Cust1   |
|Order |05-04-2020|B       |Cust2   |
```

and I need to add a new column called "Won Quote":
If Type=Quote and exists a record in the data frame where Type=Order and Date < (Quote Date + 30 days) and Date >= (Quote Date) and Materiale = Quote Material and Customer = Quote Customer then "Won" else "Lost".
So the output should be:

```
|Type  |Date      |Material|Customer|Won Quote|
|Quote |01-01-2020|A       |Cust1   |Won      |
|Quote |01-02-2020|B       |Cust2   |Lost     |
|Quote |05-03-2020|C       |Cust3   |Lost     |
|Order |03-01-2020|A       |Cust1   |         |
|Order |05-04-2020|B       |Cust2   |         |
```

What's the way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create two separate datasets for `"Quote"` and `"Order"`,  `left_join` data by `'Material'` and `'Customer'` check if the dates are in range and assign `"Won"` or `"Lost"`.

```
library(dplyr)

df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, '%d-%m-%Y')
df1 <- subset(df, Type == "Quote")
df2 <- subset(df, Type == "Order")


left_join(df1, df2, by = c('Material', 'Customer'))  %>%
       mutate(Won_Quote = if_else(Date.y > Date.x & Date.y < (Date.x + 30), 
                          "Won", "Lost", missing = "Lost")) %>%
       group_by(Customer, Material) %>%
       summarise(Won_Quote = if (any(Won_Quote == "Won")) "Won" else "Lost")

# Customer Material Won_Quote
#  <fct>    <fct>    <chr>    
#1 Cust1    A        Won      
#2 Cust2    B        Lost     
#3 Cust3    C        Lost
```

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. But if the dataframe has 2 or more order with the same characteristics it duplicates the rows. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: See updated answer it will return you one row for each `Customer` and `Material`. If you need more columns add them in `group_by`.

Answer (score 1):

Loading the data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Type = c("Quote", "Quote", "Quote", "Order", "Order") %>% factor(levels = c("Quote", "Order")),
  Date = c("01-01-2020", "01-02-2020", "05-03-2020", "03-01-2020", "05-04-2020") %>% 
    as.Date(format = "%d-%m-%Y"),
  Material = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B") %>% factor(levels = c("A", "B", "C")),
  Customer = paste0("Cust", c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2)) %>% factor(levels = paste0("Cust", 1:3))
)

df

   Type       Date Material Customer
1 Quote 2020-01-01        A    Cust1
2 Quote 2020-02-01        B    Cust2
3 Quote 2020-03-05        C    Cust3
4 Order 2020-01-03        A    Cust1
5 Order 2020-04-05        B    Cust2
```

At first I wanted to use `mutate` but your logical statement was too convoluted. This `for` loop is ugly but should work:

```
df$`Won Quote` <- NA

for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  if (df[i, "Type"] == "Quote" &
      any((df$Type == "Order") & 
          (df$Date < df[i, "Date"] + 30) & 
          (df$Material == df[i, "Material"]) & 
          (df$Customer == df[i, "Customer"])
         )
      ) df$`Won Quote`[i] <- "Won"
  else df$`Won Quote`[i] <- "Lost"
}

df

   Type       Date Material Customer Won Quote
1 Quote 2020-01-01        A    Cust1       Won
2 Quote 2020-02-01        B    Cust2      Lost
3 Quote 2020-03-05        C    Cust3      Lost
4 Order 2020-01-03        A    Cust1      Lost
5 Order 2020-04-05        B    Cust2      Lost
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know that the logical status is complex. I want to avoid a cycle.....I thought that I could split the data frame in two: Order and Quote and make a Join under conditions...could it be a way out?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. But I don't think you can escape using something similar to a for loop, because for each element of the Quote data frame, you have to check against all the Order data frame to see if there's a match.